# Why object property undefined in another method from the same object but not undefined in other?

Tags: javascript, laravel, babeljs

Ok, so I've been struggling with something I think it's pretty simple. Not sure if it's the Babel compiler or what. So I've got this class:

```js
export default class animateFormClass {

    constructor(formSelector, buttonElement = null, currentCard = null, prevCard = null, nextCard = null) {
        this.form = document.querySelector(formSelector);
        this.direction = 'forward';
        this.progressBar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
        this.opacity = this.opacityLeft = 0;
        this.buttonElement = buttonElement;
        this.currentCard = currentCard;
        this.prevCard = prevCard;
        this.nextCard = nextCard;
    }

    animateForm() {
        if (this.direction === 'forward') {

            if (this.nextCard !== null) {
                this.fadeOut = setInterval(this.fadeOutAnimation, 10);
                this.updateProgressBar;
            }
        } else if (this.direction === 'back') {

            if (this.prevCard !== null) {
                this.fadeOut = setInterval(this.fadeOutAnimation, 10);
                this.updateProgressBar;
            }
        }

    }
    fadeOutAnimation() {
        this.opacity = this.opacity - 0.05;
        console.log(this.opacity, this.currentCard);
        if (this.opacity >= 0) {
            this.currentCard.style.opacity = this.opacity;
        } else {
            this.currentCard.classList.add('d-none');
            this.fadeIn = setInterval(this.fadeInAnimation, 10);
            clearInterval(this.fadeOut);
        }
    }

    fadeInAnimation() {
        this.opacityLeft = this.opacityLeft + 0.1;
        let cardElement;

        if (this.direction === 'forward') {
            cardElement = this.nextCard;
        } else if (this.direction === 'back') {
            cardElement = this.prevCard;
        }

        cardElement.classList.remove('d-none');

        if (this.opacityLeft <= 1) {
            cardElement.style.opacity = this.opacityLeft;
        } else {
            clearInterval(this.fadeIn);
        }
    }

    updateProgressBar() {
        let activeElement = this.progressBar.querySelector('.active');
        let nextListElement = activeElement.nextElementSibling;
        let prevListElement = activeElement.previousElementSibling;

        if (this.direction === 'forward') {
            if (nextListElement !== null) {
                activeElement.classList.remove('active');
                activeElement.classList.add('step-completed');
                nextListElement.classList.add('active');
            }
        } else if (this.direction === 'back') {
            if (prevListElement !== null) {
                activeElement.classList.remove('active');
                prevListElement.classList.remove('step-completed');
                prevListElement.classList.add('active');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and from another file I'm importing the class like this:

```
import animateFormClass from './animateForm';
```

Ok so in this file I've got some code in which I update some of the object properties but in the `animateForm()` method the properties seem to be OK BUT when those same object properties are used by the other method called `fadeOutAnimation()` I've got this message of undefined in the `this.currentCard` property.

Here's the code in which I make the class instance:

```js
if (document.getElementById('register')) {
    let animate = new animateFormClass('#register');
    let currentCard, prevCard, nextCard;
    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('next')) {
            animate.direction = 'forward';
            animate.currentCard = e.target.closest('fieldset');
            animate.nextCard = animate.currentCard.nextElementSibling;
            animate.animateForm();
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('prev')) {
            animate.direction = 'back';
            animate.animateForm(e.target);
        }
    });
}
```

I get the error when the `animate.animateForm()` method is called. My environment is working on a PHP web app using Laravel and using the watch task that Laravel has out of the box.

EDIT:

Thank you for your help, I was able to fix it. If anyone was wondering, I changed all the methods of the class as properties and used the arrow function syntax. So thanks again!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Does the error say `Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined`?

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez I get ``` Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
``` making reference to the ```this.currentCard.classList.add('d-none');``` line.

Comment: @VLAZ I think you are right, it has to do with the this keywork usage. Because I just checked and the value of "this" in the fadeOut method is "window". OK I  still have not solved it but I least I know where the issue is coming from, thanks!

Comment: @MissSandwich the `this` context is lost because of the way you're passing the callback. JavaScript uses delayed context instantiation, so *basically* `this` is determined at the time you invoke a function. Also, *basically* it will be the object that you're invoking a function *from*, so `a.f()` will set `this` in `f` to `a` (the part before the `.` while if you have `a.b.c.f()` the context will be `a.b.c`. If you do `g = a.f` and then execute `g()` then there is no object you're executing the function from (no `.`, so nothing before it) and thus `this` will be `undefined`.

Comment: That is essentially what happens when you pass `this.someFunction` to be executed later. There are special rules for that event but in your case `window` is automatically assigned as `this`. [You can check for more info on how the `this` keyword works here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). To see how to avoid the problem, check the other question I've linked

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you very much. I will have to take a look at this lol. Thanks again for helping me :)

Comment: @VLAZ I fixed it! I used arrow functions, thank you very much, sir! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I was able to fix it. If anyone was wondering, I changed all the methods of the class as properties and used the arrow function syntax. So thanks again!!!

Here's the new code:

```
export default class animateFormClass {

constructor(formSelector) {
    this.form = document.querySelector(formSelector);
    this.direction = null;
    this.progressBar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
    this.opacity = this.opacityLeft = 0;
    this.buttonElement = null;
    this.currentCard = null;
    this.prevCard = null;
    this.nextCard = null;

    this.animateForm = (buttonElement) => {
        this.buttonElement = buttonElement;
        this.currentCard = this.buttonElement.closest('fieldset');
        this.nextCard = this.currentCard.nextElementSibling;
        this.prevCard = this.currentCard.previousElementSibling;

        if(this.direction === 'forward') {          
            if(this.nextCard !== null) {
                this.fadeOut = setInterval(() => { this.fadeOutAnimation() }, 10);
                this.updateProgressBar();               
            }            
        }
        else if(this.direction === 'back') {    
            if(this.prevCard !== null) {
                this.fadeOut = setInterval(() => { this.fadeOutAnimation() }, 10);
                this.updateProgressBar();
            }
        }
    }

    this.fadeOutAnimation = () => {
        this.opacity = this.opacity - 0.05; 
        if(this.opacity >= 0) {
            this.currentCard.style.opacity = this.opacity;
        }
        else {
            this.currentCard.classList.add('d-none');
            this.fadeIn = setInterval(this.fadeInAnimation, 10);
            clearInterval(this.fadeOut);
        }
    }

    this.fadeInAnimation = () => {
        this.opacityLeft = this.opacityLeft + 0.1;
        let cardElement;

        if(this.direction === 'forward') {
            cardElement = this.nextCard;            
        }
        else if(this.direction === 'back') {
        cardElement = this.prevCard;
        }

        cardElement.classList.remove('d-none');

        if(this.opacityLeft <= 1) {
            cardElement.style.opacity = this.opacityLeft;
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(this.fadeIn);
        }
    }

    this.updateProgressBar = () => {
        let activeElement = this.progressBar.querySelector('.active');
        let nextListElement = activeElement.nextElementSibling;
        let prevListElement = activeElement.previousElementSibling;

        if(this.direction === 'forward') {
            if(nextListElement !== null) {
                activeElement.classList.remove('active');
                activeElement.classList.add('step-completed');
                nextListElement.classList.add('active');
            }
        }
        else if(this.direction === 'back') {
            if(prevListElement !== null) {
                activeElement.classList.remove('active');
                prevListElement.classList.remove('step-completed');
                prevListElement.classList.add('active');
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing setInterval(this.fadeOutAnimation, 10), 'this' inside 'fadeOutAnimation' is binded by window. Use setInterval(() => { this.fadeOutAnimation() }, 10); It preserves 'this' context.